# I cant find that mosquitto_sub performing the same option as cert_reqs in mosquitto_tls_opts_set

Tags: mosquitto

I want to find **mosquitto_sub/pub command option** like to `cert_reqs` option in

```
mosquitto_tls_opts_set(mosq, cert_reqs, tls_version, ciphers); // C++ Code
```

I want to connect to the broker using only the ca.crt file.

When I set cert_reqs=0. I can connect to the broker using only the ca.crt file.

But I couldn't find this option in mosquitto_sub/pub cmd.

Answer (score 1):

From the mosquitto_sub man [page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html):

> **--insecure**
>
> When using certificate based encryption, this option disables verification of the server hostname in the server certificate. This
> can be useful when testing initial server configurations but makes it
> possible for a malicious third party to impersonate your server
> through DNS spoofing, for example. Use this option in testing only. If
> you need to resort to using this option in a production environment,
> your setup is at fault and there is no point using encryption.